# How to draw error bar with two categories in x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a error bar chart with standard error like uploaded excel file. How can I do these?

[image]

Using ggplot2 I have tried to plot with portion of data.

```
df <- data.frame(sampletype = c("DW","DW","DW","WW","WW","WW","DPW","DPW"),
                 site = c("Rural HH", "Rural farm", "Urban market","Rural HH", 
                          "Rural farm", "Urban market","Rural HH", "Rural farm"),
                 ESBL_EC = c(5,10,38,90,90,98,76,68), 
                 Carbapenem = c(0,0,0,8,5,30,5,8))

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=df, 
            aes(x=site, y=ESBL_EC, color=site)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="white")

p + 
  scale_color_grey() + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

I want to draw excel file like chart with error bar.

Comment: do you have the values for the error bars already calculated?

Comment: The columns in your data don't all match the labels in your sample chart. Which variables / values do you really want to plot?

Comment: @roman ESBL_EC_se= c(0.03, 0.05, 0.08,0.05,0.05,0.03,0.07,0.08) & Carbapenem_se=c(0,0,0,0.04,0.03,0.07,0.04,0.04)

Comment: @Z.Lin want to plot x axis= ESBL_EC & Carbapenem & y axis=prevalence. I have taken only first 8 values of the given plot to test

Answer (score 0):

Your question (including clarification in comments) is unclear. Here's my best guess at what would match the sample chart above, though that chart doesn't seem to show error bars either (at least not error bars as you defined in your comment).

```
df2 <- reshape2::melt(df, 
                      measure.vars = c("ESBL_EC", "Carbapenem"),
                      value.name = "prevalence")

ggplot(df2, aes(x = site, y = prevalence, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(~ sampletype, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Another question if I want to rearrange sampletype in order (DW,DPW,WW), what will be the change in code?

Comment: @Md.RayhanulIslam You can convert sampletype to a factor with levels in your preferred order before passing the dataframe into `ggplot()`.